# Phase-sensitive-detector

Tags: fpga, signal-processing, phase

I'm working on a phase-sensitive-detector that uses an FPGA for signal processing.For an input of a pure sinusoid with known frequency and in the range of 1 Vrms, I need to find the phase of the input in reference to a produced reference signal.
My math is as follows:
$$A*sin(w_0t+\phi) * sin(w_0t) = \frac{A}{2} [cos(\phi)-cos(2w_0t+\phi)]$$
$$A*sin(w_0t+\phi) * cos(w_0t) = \frac{A}{2} [sin(\phi)+sin(2w_0t+\phi)]$$

where my input signal is $$A*sin(w_0t+\phi)$$ I'm going to filter out the larger frequency components and will be left with $$sin(\phi),  
 cos(\phi)$$  with which I can determine the phase from there.

Then I realised I need to give a DC offset to the input signal for A-D conversion, because ADC has a range of 0-Va. I got lost there. The new equation looks like$$[V_{off}+A*sin(w_0t+\phi)]*sin(w_0t) = V_{off}* sin(w_0t)+\frac{A}{2} [cos(\phi)-cos(2w_0t+\phi)]$$ Should I then filter out the frequencies w_0 and above? I kinda need reassurance. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you measure the output code from the ADC when just your DC bias level is applied, then you can simply subtract that value from all ADC samples and the DC offset is gone.

Comment: Thanks. My project documents describe the input signal as "in the range of 1 Vrms". I took it as the maximum. So if I give 0.5 Vrms, wouldn't things go south? What if signal from the signal generator wasn't so precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine. It may help to think of it as a "one-channel" DFT (discrete Fourier transform).

The thing that you're missing is the fact that if there's a DC bias on the ADC data, this gets converted by the multiplication into AC components that have zero mean as long as the integration period is an integer number of cycles of your reference ω<sub>0</sub>. These components will get filtered out and have no effect on your Asin(Φ) and Acos(Φ) outputs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way?

You can do what most folk would turn to, an exclusive or gate: -

[image]

You would convert your sine wave and reference phase to square waves (using a comparator) and just feed them to the EXOR. The average level of the output represents the phase between the two signals. In example 1 that is zero, in example 2, the average level has risen. In example 3 the two signals are nearly output phase and the average level is nearly an analogue level equivalent to logic 1. In example 4 the two signals are antiphase and the output = logic 1.

Midpoint i.e. halfway between 0 and logic level 1 is 90 degrees.

Comment: This approach relies entirely on the zero crossings, which makes it very much subject to noise (which causes jitter on the zero crossings), and makes it impossible to resolve phase differences that are smaller than the sample period. The DSP approach that the OP is pursuing (essentially a 1-channel DFT) is much more robust against noise and gives higher phase resolution.

Comment: Robustness against amplitude variation might be of significant importance.

Comment: Are you trying to suggest that the DFT phase measurement is somehow affected by amplitude? It isn't -- in fact, it gives you an accurate estimate of amplitude in addition to phase.